# Xorg log full of RandR output

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, graphics

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 on some specialised hardware that directs manipulates the HDMI output before displaying it to the screen. I am noticing that from time to time the Xorg log goes crazy with constant output as if xrandr is being called and logged again and again and again.

Afters a few days of nothing in the Xorg log these lines get repeated every 500 milliseconds.

```
[397158.319] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "UHD", prod id 0
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x0.0  594.00  3840 4016 4104 4400  2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (135.0 kHz eP)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x0.0  297.00  3840 4016 4104 4400  2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (28.1 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   85.50  1366 1436 1579 1792  768 771 774 798 +hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904 932 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x576"x0.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   74.25  1920 2558 2602 2750  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "2880x480"x0.0  108.00  2880 2944 3192 3432  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (28.1 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1440x480i"x0.0   27.00  1440 1478 1602 1716  480 488 494 525 interlace -hsync -vsync (15.7 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1440x576i"x0.0   27.00  1440 1464 1590 1728  576 580 586 625 interlace -hsync -vsync (15.6 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1440x288"x0.0   27.00  1440 1464 1590 1728  288 290 293 312 -hsync -vsync (15.6 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1720 1760 1980  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1440x240"x0.0   27.00  1440 1478 1602 1716  240 244 247 262 -hsync -vsync (15.7 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[397158.320] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
```

The hardware uses an AMD Radeon HD 8210 graphics chip but the display device that is connected to it is weird. It presents as a 4K screen but needs to be run at 1920x540 since it is half height.

It has been reported that after a while X just dies. What might be happening?

Comment: Full make and model of graphics card?

Comment: @roaima The hardware uses an AMD Radeon HD 8210 graphics chip but the display device that is connected to it is weird. It presents as a 4K screen but needs to be run at 1920x540 since it is half height.

Comment: Please add that to your question where it can be seen easily by anyone considering answering.